# Maven: Release Plugin Does Not Commit Updated Versions

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I am using the Maven release plugin.  When I run

```
mvn release:prepare
```

I am prompted with the usual about the versions

```
What is the release version for "FOO"? (foo:bar) 1.10.99999:
What is the new development version for "FOO"? (foo:bar) 1.10.100000-SNAPSHOT:
```

The process completes normally.  A tag is created and pushed to the correct repository as specified in the SCM tag:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@top.secret.repo:foo/bar.git</connection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

But the updates to the versions numbers are not committed, and thus the SNAPSHOT, in the case the `1.10.99999-SNAPSHOT` is deployed on `mvn deploy`.  It appears [others have had this issue as well but no real answer has been found](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812)

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

This is on Mac OSX.  My Maven version is as follows:

```
$ brew info maven
  maven: stable 3.2.5
  http://maven.apache.org/
  /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3 (76 files, 8.0M) *
  Built from source
  From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/maven.rb

$ mvn --version
    Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T13:58:10-07:00)
    Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
    Java version: 1.7.0_67, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: What's the version of the maven-release-plugin you're using? Don't guess, but take a look at the console output.

Comment: What about `mvn release:perform`? I don't see a hint about here?

Comment: @RobertScholte `maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli)`

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not sure, we are not using that here.  The abridged flow is `mvn release:prepare` and then `mvn deploy`

Comment: Could you try `2.5.1`, all 2.5.x releases were mainly released for GIT related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: when facing issues with a specific maven-plugin, verify if you are using the latest version and try to upgrade first.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the version from `2.3.2` to `2.5.3` solves the issue for me. Definitely, something isn't right with the `2.3.2` version of the `maven-release-plugin`